# CloverETL Graph configuration is invalid - no field elements for 'recordName1' have been found

Tags: cloveretl

Trying to build a CloverETL graph. Currently it's quite simple - just a DBInputTable leading into a UniversalDataWriter element. It was working fine, and then for no reason that I can determine started producing the above error every time I try to run the graph. Full error log at http://pastebin.com/UiNrEfqG

I have no idea what I changed to make it start doing this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to sort this problem out, could you add how. I think this could be helpful for other people with similar issues.

Comment: Honestly I can't remember, unfortunately. I think I deleted the graph and started again, and the new graph worked - never did work out what the problem had been.

Answer (score 1):

You probably deleted all fields in metadata record by accident. Double click on the edge between components and create fields that matches query from DBInputTable.

Or let DBInputTable extract metadata for you, right click on DBInputTable and choose *Extract metadata* option